# openClose Door program using a constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to build a program, using a constructor, that has three doors and switches them from open to close. Front is open, Side is closed, Back is closed. Then I am trying switch to Front is closed, Side is open, and Back is opened. My program is working correctly, however I feel I did not use the constructor the correct way. Also for my tester class is there a better way to switch the state of the door?
Thank you!
Door class

```
public class Door {

String name, state; // state is either "open" or "closed"


/**
 * Constructor class that receives two arguments.
 *
 * @param name
 * @param state
 */
public Door(String name, String state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
}

public String state() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String name() {
    return name;
}

// method sets door state to "open"
public void open() {

    state = "open";
} // end open
// method sets door state to "closed"

public void close() {

    state = "closed";

} // end close

public String output() {
    return "Door name: " + name
            + '\n' + "State of door: " + state;
}
} // end class Door
```

DoorTester class

```
public class Doors {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Door front = new Door("Front", "open");
    Door side = new Door("Side", "closed");
    Door back = new Door("Back", "closed");

    System.out.println(front.output());
    System.out.println(side.output());
    System.out.println(back.output());

    if (front.state.equals("open")) {
        front.close();

    }
    System.out.println(front.output());
    if(side.state.equals("closed")){
        side.open();
    }
    System.out.println(side.output());

   if(back.state.equals("closed")){
      back.open();
   }
   System.out.println(back.output());
}
}
```

Comment: In your scenario your doors have only two states, so why not simply use a `boolean` (`isOpen`?) to indicate their state?

Comment: Why do you feel you didn't use the constructor properly?

Comment: Actually I was just confused with my tester class and that I was using a String state instead of boolean, which made me think I was using the constructor wrong. However, in my original code I looked at it again and it is used properly. @Tgsmith61591

Answer (score 0):

Having a string that indicates "open" or "closed" is a bit risky (for instance, you make a typo (which can be hard to detect later) and you type in "apen" or "clesed". Boolean is a bit better solution simply because a door can be either closed or open...

```
public class Door {

private String name; //remember to put these as private (by default they're package-private)
private boolean isOpen;


/**
 * Constructor class that receives two arguments.
 *
 * @param name
 * @param state
 */
public Door(String name, boolean isOpen) {
    this.name = name;
    this.isOpen = isOpen;
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    return isOpen;
}

public void setState(boolean state) {
    this.isOpen = state;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String name() {
    return name;
}

// method sets door state to "open"
public void open() {

    isOpen = true;
} // end open
// method sets door state to "closed"

public void close() {

    isOpen = false;

} // end close

public String output() {
    return "Door name: " + name
            + '\n' + "State of door: " + (isOpen ? "open" : "closed");
}
} // end class Door
```

or if you want a "open" or "closed" response from the class, just use a simple operation (called ternary operator):

```
public String state() { return isOpen ? "open" : "closed"; }
```

which is basically the same as:

```
public String state() {
    if(isOpen)
        return "open";
    else
        return "closed;
}
```

also as Jon says, having a `setState` and `open`/`closed` method seams redudant... My suggestion would be something like:

```
 public changeState() { isOpen = !isOpen; }
```

since you can only close a door if it's open, or vice versa... but it all depends what you want to do with it.

Comment: I'm going to nitpick here: the default visibility of member variables is *package-private*, **not** public - there's quite a difference between the two. I'd probably opt for keeping two separate `open()` and `close()` methods in this case as well: `door.open();` is much more descriptive to future maintainers than `door.setState(true);`

Comment: The issue with toggles is that you have to check either beforehand or afterwards whether or not the object is in the state you want it to be in, which is a conditional statement potentially followed by the toggle call. With `open()` and `close()`, the current state of the door is ignored - after the call you can guarantee that the door is in the correct state with no additional checking needed.

Comment: @JonK again, true, but it all depends on how the code which calls it works. If it's expected for the program to 'know' if it's closed or open, he'd also have to check (if it's open close, if it's not, open)... but then again, I guess he could just set it in reverse (`door.setState(!door.isOpen());`)

Comment: @NemanjaT for my tester class would I have this code...'Door front = new Door("Front", front.setState(front.isOpen());' or how would I set a door to open because NetBeans is saying "void" not allowed here. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamWhite you can't do `Door front = new Door("front", front.setState(...` because the second argument is a boolean, while the method is void (1) and because object `front` isn't declared yet (2). Set it up simply like `Door front = new Door("front", true);` or `Door front = new Door("front", false);` and to later change state just do `front.setState(true);` or `front.setState(false);`..... `true` or `false` say if the door is open (`front.isOpen()` would return `true` or `false`)